# How do I get the chest that is down the very thin hole in The Hole?

Tags: candy-box-2

In the quest called The Hole, there are 3 chests. I have been able to get two of them, but the third appears to be in an isolated cavern that can only be accessed by going down a hole that is two thin for the character to fit through. Specifically, it's the chest in the following picture:

[image: Chest in cavern through hole]

How can I get to that chest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need the sponge.

[image]

You can get it by jumping in the ocean.

Answer (score 1):

You need a sponge to use squeeze

Answer (score 1):

You can find item Sponge in the sea. With it you can "Squeeze" yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have to get to the end of the sea level. Then you have to squeeze yourself above the hole and you'll fall through it.